# SQL: Invalid column name eventhough column is there?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, spring-data

I have the following `Spring Data` Query:

```
@Query(value = "select * from person where person_id =?! and family_id not in (select related_person_id from relationships where related_family_id = ?1)", native query = true)
Person getPerson(String personId);
```

I am getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

However, I know that all my column names for the two tables in my query are correct, what could ne causing this?

Comment: shouldn't there be " 's around that query?

Comment: Can you post the tables?

Comment: Can you post the tables and the entity beans?

Comment: @Stultuske sorry I edited it, that was a typo

Comment: Post your both table also to check the issue

Comment: I know that the columns are in the tables though?

Comment: Can you show how you set the values for the variables `?!` and `?1`?  I'm suspicious that person_ID and related_Famiily_ID are not being able to be bound to the variables you've defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know the structure of your data but your spring data query has many typos and errors, the standard query method should be:

```
@Query(value = "select * from person where person_id =?1 and family_id not in (select related_person_id from relationships where related_family_id = ?2)", nativeQuery = true);
Person findByPersonIdAndRelatedFamilyId(String personId, String relatedFamilyId);
```

also check your inner select query -I don't know the relation between `family_id` and `related_person_id`- but it should return a `family_id` column or an aliased column as `family_id` may be thats why you're receiving such error ..